# Drupal 7 - Server Error 500 when adding a Filter to views

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, internal-server-error

For some reason when I try adding a filter to any view that I have, I receive the Server Error 500.

In Google Chrome I get 
[this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdaSi.jpg)

In Firefox I get this [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNf5c.jpg)

To be detailed, I have a view that currently displays published articles. All Articles are translated into Spanish and English. I am trying to add the filter: Content:language and set it to user current language.

When I save, the page refreshes and the temporary changes notice is shown. I try saving a second time and the Server Error comes up. This happens for both web browsers.

Could it be a that I have to enable a read/write for a certain file? If so, I don't know which file to look for.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me ? I have been at it for about 13 hours...

Comment: Did you took a look to eror_log file and also Drupal "recent log messages" admin page?

Comment: @Rainfall . Thank you for responding. Taking your advice, I checked the log searched the error text and found a solution in Drupal's forum. Will post the answer.

Comment: @Rainfall Thank you again! I wouldn't have found the solution so quickly without you.

Comment: Very glad for you =)

Answer (score 0):

After taking the advice from @Rainfall in the comment, I found another post on Drupal's forum with the solution/ patch for this issue.

[Here is the post with the solution](https://www.drupal.org/node/1685144#comment-10635170)

Comment #9 gave a patch that worked for others and it worked for me too. More in depth info on the issue is there as well.